# is there special FFT technique for function of angle argument?

Tags: fast-fourier-transform

I started working with molecular modelling and stuck at the following problem.

I need to calculate dihedral interaction energy by hand. The simplest form of the equation is $V = \frac{Va}{2} * \left( 1 + \cos{\left( n \phi - \phi_0 \right)} \right )$. This refers to the **energy term**. In the real world there may be more than one terms - one, two etc...

From experiment I have plot of dependency $V$ on $\phi$, where is $\phi$ belongs to the $\left[ 0; 2\pi \right]$ interval and increases by some value (in my case $d\phi = 5$ so I have $72$ points). By visual analysis I can conclude that I have more than one energy term, because final plot is the sum of different cosines. So I want to do FFT on the $V$ data. But as soon as i know FFT applies only to the functions which are determined on the time-domain but not angle-domain...

So my question is: how to conduct FFT on angle-domain determined function? Which modifications should I apply to my data?

Thank you!

**EDIT** sample FFT magnitudes are added

[sample energy profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1e0N6.png) [magnitudes of FFT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XW3o.png)

Comment: I think you're just hung up on terminology here. Time domain is just a common terminology in basic Fourier analysis, to contrast with the dual frequency domain. But the physical meaning of the variable can be anything you want. Like an angle.

Comment: @Raskolnikov so you want to say that I could do direct FFT on my energy data? In that case what will be the meaning of the "frequencies"?

Comment: If we take the example you give, there is only one cosine term, so if you transform you get a peak at $n$. So whatever you call $n$. I suppose it's still called a frequency.

Comment: You can compute directly the FFT of the vector $x(m),m \in 0 \ldots,N, N= 350$ you [plotted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1e0N6.png), it will give $x(m)=\frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=0}^N X(k) e^{2i \pi mk/N}$ ie. a sum of sines. In that case, use windowing (hanning window).

Comment: @Raskolnikov I think there is more than one cosine term - see attachment picture with FFT magnitudes

Comment: That doesn't matter, does it? That just changes the number of peaks in the Fourier spectrum, not what you call the variable indicating the location of the peaks.

Comment: ok, thank you! you helped me a lot!